# svn log of svn:externals properties in a directory

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I'm working on a project where there is a directory with a multiline svn:externals property. We would like to perform an 'svn log' of changes in the directory, only for the svn:externals property, not for changes in files and subdirectories, How could we do that? Thanks.

I tried several alternatives with svn log.

After the execution of a command, I would like to see the log message and revision number where there were changes in the svn:externals property.

Comment: "I tried several alternatives with svn log" - could you please [edit] and share them so we get an idea what you are trying to accomplish?